# why my post not redirecting to custom created single-show.php file?

Tags: posts

i am registered custom post type name is 'show' in **function.php**,and also i created **single-show.php**
file where i want my custom post to be show when i follow the permalink of post ,this only to for 'show' custom post type but it's post not redirecting to single-show.php..please can any one guide me how to do it..

i am showing simple code of **single-show.php**

```
<?php
if($post_type == 'Show') { 

                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

           echo '<h1>'.get_the_title().'</h1>';
                endwhile;



 }
?>
```

please tell me what i am doing wrong..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use default WordPress loop for single pages of post types...

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        echo '<h1>'.get_the_title().'</h1>';
        // Post Content here
    } // end while
} else{
   esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts found.' );
}
?>
```